# Tense after 'still'

Tags: tense, tense-agreement

> Jack **stopped** being a lad for a long time ago, it was amusing to see someone still **try** to mother him.

Above is an example sentence I made.

Previously, I wrote 'tried' instead of 'try', but I got a suggestion that I should change the verb into 'try', which is present tense. I wonder why since the whole sentence meant to be in the past.

I did some basic research. [LearnenglishBritishCouncil.org](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/still-and-no-longer-already-and-yet) said that still can be past, present or future tense.
So I wonder is there any reason why **try** is a better choice than **tried**? Or should I just ignore the suggestion?

---

I think I figured it out by myself. As [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing) and [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv214.shtml) said that after word such as allow, permit, see, hear, make, let, or other verbs for perception (e.g., feel), the pattern would be subject + verb + object + infinitive (without to) or -ing.

> She **heard** the doorbell **ring** and went to answer it.

Comment: When you use *it's* is it short of "it is" or "It was"? Is the person talking an action that is on-going, or one that is definitely in the past?

Comment: "It was", I made an edit to the post to make it more clear.

Comment: This is a conflation of two constructions. Either it should be _see that someone still **tries** to mother him_ (with _that_) or it should be _see someone still try to mother him_ (without _that_ but with infinitive -- not present tense -- _try_ ). The reason is that _that_ only introduces a tensed clause, never an infinitive or gerund. As for the first sentence, it's a conflation of _He hasn't been a lad for a long time_ and _He stopped being a lad a long time ago_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, you're correct I made another mistake in that post. 'That' you have mentioned shouldn't be there. So the suggestion is correct? That after 'still' I should use 'try' instead of 'tried'? But the BrithisCouncil.org said I can use past tense. I am really confused, could you explain to me why? Thank you.

Comment: In *...it was amusing to see someone still try to mother him*, *try* is not the present tense. It may look a bit like it, but it is the infinitive. The only other option there is *trying*. The other version of the sentence (*it was amusing to see THAT someone...* is very different. If you use that version, you have lots of options (I think I would say *was still trying*). This is probably the kind of sentence the British Council is talking about.